# How to join more than two tables using Lightswitch LINQ query

Tags: linq, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am new to lightswitch as well as linq, i am using `LS 2015`. I want to know how to display the data of one table in other table's screen.

For example I have `job vacancies`, where I want to show candidate professional information who has applied for job. These two tables are related through Candidate personal ID, means a foreign key between candidate personal table and professional table.

The relation is as follows
`JobVacancies->CandidatePersonalInfor->candidateProfessionalInfo`. They are many to one related.

I have written a `linq query` to fetch data, where i have included some other tables also, my code is as follows

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: there is no code attached in post (...my code is as follows...)

Comment: You could create and consume a view instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the relationships you describe between the entities? If so, you'll have the ability to add and drop the details you require onto the form in the designer. The entities and their properties will be in the left pane of the screen designer.

If the join operation is more complex, you can use a WCF RIA Service to create a composite entity, as described in http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/2226/Creating-a-WCF-RIA-Service-for-Visual-Studio-2013.aspx